# SQL Shell(psql) why won't it let me enter the password?

Tags: postgresql

```
Server [localhost]:
PRESS ENTER;
Database [postgres]:
PRESS ENTER;
Port [5432]:
PRESS ENTER;
Username [postgres]:
```

psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

How do I enter the password?

Comment: Please post your `pg_hba.conf` configuration file.

Comment: Huh? Who generates these prompts? My `psql` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set a `pg_hba.conf` config file

Comment: Gee, that's really helpful.